# Looking for a good VBA treemap implementation

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VBA map object similar to C++ STL map class for use in Excel 2010. I am dreading writing one myself, and also dreading writing an XLL. Does anyone know of such an object freely available? Scripting.Dictionary will not do, since I need ordered iteration.

Comment: Would the dictionary be any use to you? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187234/EN-US/

Comment: No, Dictionary is a hash table that does not support ordered iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, the Collection object is available for ordered iteration. However, the only ordering available is on the item number. I eventually created a COM object exposing a std:map using the ATL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a chapter from a book, hosted on MSDN, that describes creating a binary tree, might be useful to get you started at least: [Implementing a Binary Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227540%28VS.60%29.aspx)

They do mention that there should be sample code on the cd, not sure if you'd be able to download that from there or from the publisher, nor am I sure under what license that sourcecode is provided.

Comment: I saw that, thanks.  It's not a balanced tree, and it lacks code for deleting, searching, etc.

Comment: @Thomas: Otherwise, can't you just cheat. Create a Automation compatible library in C++ or C# or something and use the built in classes in there as your tree and then use that from your VBA code. If you just want to store simple datatypes like strings or numbers I'd thought it would be fairly easy, and you'll get to use a well tested class instead of writing your own.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Instead of writing a full-blown XLL, expose a C++ map object via COM. Do you think that would be easier?

Comment: @Thomas, or go ahead and do it as part of an XLL if you don't actually need an object you can manipulate in VBA but just want to use a map in some algorithm. This appears to be getting easier and easier (see for example http://exceldna.codeplex.com/). I assume C++.NET has a std::map implementation that would work for you...

Comment: @Thomas: Didn't even know about XLL, sounds like an interesting option though.